# The opposite of Weyl's theorem on Lie algebras

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero, and $\mathfrak{g}$ a semisimple Lie algebra over it. By Weyl's theorem, we know that any finite-dimensional representation $V$ of it is semisimple.

The question is: Is the opposite of this theorem also true, and if not, what is a counterexample?

NB by semisimple representation I mean a sum of simple representations and simple representation is the one that does not have a subrepresentation.

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/q/23085/27465

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is true (assuming $\mathfrak{g}$ is finite dimensional). Indeed, assume every finite dimensional representation is completely reducible. Then, since the adjoint representation is completely reducible, it follows that $\mathfrak{g}$ is reductive.

If $Z(\mathfrak{g})\neq 0$, then fix $z\in Z(\mathfrak{g})\backslash\{0\}$ and decompose $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{g}'\oplus kz$. Define a representation of $\mathfrak{g}$ on $V=k^2$ so that $x\in\mathfrak{g'}$ acts trivially
$$x.{a\choose b}={0\choose 0}$$ and 
$$z.{a\choose b}={b\choose 0}.$$
Then, $$W=\left\{{a\choose 0}\mid a\in k\right\}$$ is a submodule with no complement.

Comment: This is a more logical complement than I first thought was meant (namely whether the module being semisimple implied it being finite dimensional, which is obviously false).

Comment: @David Hill Thanks! So is then the notion of reductive (finite-dimensional) Lie algebras characterised similarily by saying that any finite dimensional representation of such is completely reducible (i.e. direct sum of irreducibles $\neq$ simples)

Comment: @Filip92 Reductive means $(\mathrm{semisimple})\oplus(\mathrm{abelian})$.

Comment: @DavidHill Sorry, I got confused with different notions. What I have stated is true for any finite-dim. Lie algebra (that you can decompose any finite-dim. representation of it into indecomposables).