# Representation theory for compact simply connected lie groups

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ a simply connected compact lie group. Now, I know that

> Given $H$ a Lie group. To give an homomorphism of Lie group $G \rightarrow H$ is equivalent to give an homomorphism $\mathfrak{g} \rightarrow \mathfrak{h} $. Where $\mathfrak{g}$ and $\mathfrak{h}$ are the Lie algebras of $G$ and $H$ respectively.

The first question is: how to prove this? Can anyone suggest me a text where to found the proof or also only a trace of it?

**If** it is true I think that can be prooved that

> $\mathfrak{g}$ is semisimple

It is sufficient to take $H=GL(V)$ where $V$ is an arbitrary finite dimensionale vector space.

The second question is: is it true this statement and the trace of the proof?

Comment: I think the questions being asked are: Is a Lie group homomorphism "equivalent to" a Lie algebra homomorphism? And does this allow us to prove that for a simply-connected compact group its Lie algebra must be semisimple. The answer to the first question is yes ($G$ being simply-connected is vital here). The second assertion is true (simply-connected compact Lie groups are semisimple) but I don't know if that is the way to prove it.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg $G$ is always simply-connected in my questions.

Comment: @Callum Thank you

Comment: OK and sorry, for my earlier (now deleted) comment I had not read the question well enough. Now, for question 1, one direction (from groups to algebras) is basic, and the converse is one of the fundamental theorems of Lie theory, called e.g. "Lie's Second Theorem" here: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Lie%27s+three+theorems (and probably under a similar name in every reputable source). As for question 2, it's possible but I don't see right away to prove it from that. What do you mean by "It is sufficient to take ..." -- you think that is is sufficient for a proof? Then what's the proof idea?

Comment: $\mathfrak{g}$ is a lie algebra finite dimensional. So it is semisimple if each of his representation is fully reducible. Now $G$ is compact so each $G$-representation (regular) finite dimensional is fully reducible. Now a $G$-representation is a homomorphism of $G$ into $GL(V)$, so if i take $H=GL(V)$...

Comment: Well if you know all those things ... Note that one can get more out of a different route; in general, the Lie algebra of a compact group is $\text{semisimple} \oplus \text{abelian}$; on the group level the abelian part corresponds to copies of the torus $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$, which of course are not simply connected; so by your simply connected hypothesis, you have no abelian part in your group and hence neither in the Lie algebra. But yes, your proof idea makes sense to me, if you already know full reducibility of f.d. compact Lie group representations.

Comment: That isn't quite correct. If each representation is completely reducible then it is a reductive Lie algebra (i.e. the direct sum of a semisimple one and an abelian one). So what you prove there is $G$ compact implies $G$ reductive. (Beaten to the punch but I'll leave it up)

Comment: Thanks you all. If I've understood it's sufficient to proove the full reducibility of compact Lie group. Now, to have another feedback, I proove it as consequence of the existence of a finite Haar measure... Is it right?

Comment: @Callum: If the adjoint rep is completely reducible, the Lie algebra is reductive. But if *all* (finite dim.) reps are completely reducible, the Lie algebra is necessarily semisimple. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2987417/96384

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Thanks I hadn't appreciated that distinction