# Other direction of Weyl's theorem on semisimple Lie-algebras

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

Weyl's theorem states

> Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a finite dimensional semisimple Lie-algebra over an algebraically closed field with characteristic 0. Then all finite dimensional representations are semisimple.

One can also look at the other direction

> Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a finite dimensional Lie-algebra over an algebraically closed field with characteristic 0. If all finite dimensional representations are semisimple then $\mathfrak{g}$ is semisimple.

I want to prove that direction. For that I considered the adjoint representation giving us a direct sum of irreducible subrepresentations. These correspond to the ideals of $\mathfrak{g}$. Now, I would like to show that these ideals are simple (or semisimple). But now, I am stuck showing this. I have tried to look at abelian ideals of these ideals and tried to show that they are 0, but it has not worked. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that the adjoint representation being semisimple only implies that the Lie algebra is reductive so you will need more than that

Comment: @Callum Wait, do you mean that the statement is just false or that I need more arguments in order to prove the statement? Ah, perhaps it is that I have forgotten to add that $\mathfrak{g}$ is of finite dimension. I am adding that.

Comment: Any Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ which has $\mathfrak{gl}_1$ as a quotient will have finite-dimensional representations which are not semisimple, so the issue is not a serious one.

Comment: This has been asked before (and answered), see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2987494/101420

Comment: The linked answer takes it as obvious that (as in Callum's comment) the adjoint rep being semi-simple implies that the original Lie algebra is the sum of a semisimple algebra and an abelian one. Let me know if you want some elaboration on that point

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The opposite of Weyl's theorem on Lie algebras](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2987417/the-opposite-of-weyls-theorem-on-lie-algebras)

Comment: @Vincent Yeah, I do need some clarification on that fact that it is a sum of a semisimple and an abelian Lie-algebra. It seems that this is known as a reductive Lie-algebra. I have not encountered that property yet and do not have any statements available concerning it. But anyways thanks for the link. That has already been helpful.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg It goes in the right direction, but has not yet fully answered my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**: *I have expanded this answer to try and provide more details in response to the comment below.*

Let $\mathfrak g$ be a finite-dimensional Lie algebra over an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero, and let $\mathrm{Rep}_{fd}(\mathfrak g)$ denote the category of finite-dimensional representations of $\mathfrak g$.

**Claim**: If $\mathrm{Rep}_{fd}(\mathfrak g)$ is semisimple (that is every object of $\mathrm{Rep}_{fd}(\mathfrak g)$ is semisimple) then $\mathfrak g$ is a semisimple Lie algebra.

**Definition**: Let $\mathfrak g$ be a Lie algebra over a field of characteristic zero. We say that $\mathfrak g$ is *reductive* if its radical (i.e. its largest solvable ideal) is equal to its centre. If the radical $\mathrm{rad}(\mathfrak g)$ is equal to the centre $\mathfrak z(\mathfrak g)$, then the Levi decomposition of $\mathfrak g$ will split as a direct sum of a semisimple Lie algebra and the centre of $\mathfrak g$.

*Claim 1*: If the adjoint representation $(\mathfrak g, \mathrm{ad})$ is completely reducible, then $\mathfrak g$ is reductive.

If $(\mathfrak g, \mathrm{ad})$ is completely reducible, we may write $\mathfrak g$ as a direct sum of irreducible subrepresentations,. Suppose this decomposition takes the form
$$
\mathfrak g = \bigoplus_{i=1}^k \mathfrak p_i \oplus \mathfrak g^{\mathfrak g}, 
$$
where for a $\mathfrak g$-representation $(V,\rho)$, we write $V^{\mathfrak g} = \{v \in V: \rho(g)(v)=0, \forall g\in \mathfrak g\}$, hence when $V$ is semisimple, $V^{\mathfrak g}$ is the isotypical summand of $V$ corresponding to the trivial representation. Now each $\mathfrak p_i$ is an irreducible $\mathfrak g$-representation, and hence a minimal ideal in $\mathfrak g$, thus each $\mathfrak p_i$ is a Lie algebra which has no proper ideals.

Now because the ideals $\mathfrak p_i$ form a direct sum, $[\mathfrak p_i,\mathfrak p_j]\subseteq \mathfrak p_i \cap \mathfrak p_j = \{0\}$. Thus as the $\mathfrak p_i$ are, by definition, not contained in $\mathfrak g^{\mathfrak g}$ we must have $[\mathfrak p_i,\mathfrak p_i]\neq 0$ and hence, by minimality of $\mathfrak p_i$, it follows that $[\mathfrak p_i,\mathfrak p_i]=
\mathfrak p_i$.

Thus we see that $\mathfrak g = \mathfrak s \oplus \mathfrak g^{\mathfrak g}$, where $\mathfrak s$ is a direct sum of non-abelian simple Lie algebras (and hence is semisimple) and $\mathfrak g^{\mathfrak g}$ is an abelian ideal on which $\mathfrak g$ acts by zero, *i.e.* it is the centre of $\mathfrak g$, and the claim is established.

*Claim 2*: If $\mathfrak g$ is any Lie algebra which has $\mathfrak{gl}_1$ as a quotient, then $\mathrm{Rep}_{fd}(\mathfrak g)$ is not semisimple.

*Proof*: The point here is that the quotient map $q\colon 
\mathfrak g \to \mathfrak{gl}_1$ can be used to pull back any representation of $\mathfrak{gl}_1$ to become a representation of $\mathfrak{g}$. In particular, if $\mathfrak{gl}_1$ has any representations which are not semisimple then so will $\mathfrak g$. But the map $t\mapsto t\left(\begin{array}{cc}1 & 1\\ 0 & 1\end{array}\right)$ gives a representation of $\mathfrak{gl}_1$ on $\mathsf k^2$ which has a unique proper submodule (the span of $(1,0)^\intercal$) and hence cannot be semisimple.

Finally, to establish the original Claim, notice that if $\mathrm{Rep}(\mathfrak g)$ is semisimple then certainly $(\mathfrak g, \mathrm{ad})$ is a semisimple representation and so by Claim 1, $\mathfrak g$ is reductive. But then if $\mathfrak z(\mathfrak g)\neq 0$, then since $\mathfrak g = \mathfrak s \oplus \mathfrak z(\mathfrak g)$ where $\mathfrak s$ is a semisimple ideal, it follows that $\mathfrak g/\mathfrak s \cong \mathfrak z(\mathfrak g)$, and as $\mathfrak z(\mathfrak g)$ is abelian, if $\lambda \in \mathfrak z(\mathfrak g)^*$ is a nonzero linear functional on $\mathfrak z(\mathfrak g)$, then $\lambda \colon \mathfrak z(\mathfrak g) \to \mathfrak{gl}_1$ is a surjective homomorphism of Lie algebras. Since $q\colon \mathfrak g \to \mathfrak g/\mathfrak s \cong \mathfrak z(\mathfrak g)$ is also surjective, it follows that $\lambda \circ q$ is a surjective homomorphism from $\mathfrak g$ to $\mathfrak{gl}_1$.

Therefore, it follows from Claim $2$ that if $\mathrm{Rep}_{fd}(\mathfrak g)$ is semisimple we must have $\mathfrak z(\mathfrak g)=\{0\}$ and $\mathfrak g$ is semisimple as required.

[*Note that an abelian Lie algebra $\mathfrak a$ is just a $\mathsf k$-vector space equipped with the zero Lie bracket. Thus $\mathfrak a$ can be written as a direct sum of one-dimensional subspaces which are also subalgebras. The only one-dimensional Lie algebra is the trivial one because the alternating property of the bracket forces it to vanish, and this Lie algebra is usually denoted $\mathfrak{gl}_n$.*]

Comment: Thanks for this proof. But, like in the comments above, I am not familiar with the concept of a reductive Lie-algebra. Why do we have that $\mathfrak{g}$ is the direct sum of its simple subreps and (in particular) the centre? Also, I have not seen that the centre can be represented as the direct sum of $\mathfrak{gl}_1$ (which I also have not seen before, so it is difficult following from your definition below).

Comment: Thanks for the update by the way. But would'nt I be able to prove that by just saying that I take an abelian Ideal and look at the quotient map from $\mathfrak{g} \to I$ and define the same representation with the matrix from $I \to \mathfrak{gl}(k^2)$ giving me a non semisimple representation which contradicts the assumption? And then I have no abelian Ideal which means that the Lie-algebra is semisimple.

Comment: I really like the updated answer. I wanted to type something along the lines what is now claim 1 (and its proof), so I think I don't have to any more. Regarding your question in the comment above: there is in general NO map from $\mathfrak{g}$ to $I$ (there is a map from $\mathfrak{g}/I$, but that is not useful for your construction because we want the quotient to be abelian. In the construction above we use that the semi-simple part is also an ideal so that we *do* get a map to an abelian quotient. But this is special, the radical is normally just an ideal, not a direct summand.

Comment: I realize now that by taking 'this is special' it is maybe not so clear what situation here is special. The special situation is the situation where the adjoint rep is semi-simple. If all other representations are *also* semi-simple, *then* it follows from Claim 2 that the abelian Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}^\mathfrak{g}$ in the decomposition $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{s} \oplus \mathfrak{g}^\mathfrak{g}$ must be just $\{0\}$, since otherwise  $\mathfrak{g}^\mathfrak{g}$ would be an abelian quotient of $\mathfrak{g}$ that can be used to construct a non-semisimple representation.

Comment: (So if all representations are semi-simple,  $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{s} \oplus \mathfrak{g}^\mathfrak{g}$ reduces to $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{s}$ showing that $\mathfrak{g}$ is semi-simple since $\mathfrak{s}$ was semi-simple by construction. But you probably already got that part.)

Comment: Aaargh there is a typo in my first comment and it is too late to edit now. I meant to say "(there is a map from $\mathfrak{g}$ to $\mathfrak{g}/I$ but that is not useful for your construction because we want the quotient to be abelian)".

Comment: @Vincent Ok, so one needs that the abelian ideal is a direct summand in order to get a map $\mathfrak{g} \to I$. But that follows since a completely reducible module has the property that any proper submodule has a complement which when talking about the ad-modules any ideal has an ideal as a complement. That seems to work and is a bit more elementary which might be better suited for me. Anyways it is nice to have seen some insight and stuff coming in the future.